# Timeout error when uploading video to Vimeo through their API

Tags: python, tornado, vimeo-api

I have a Python script that takes advantage of the latest Vimeo API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/) to upload some videos to my Vimeo account.

Here is what, in a slightly simplified form, the script basically does:

```py
from vimeo import VimeoClient
vimeo = VimeoClient('my_token_here')
uid = vimeo.upload('/path/to/file.mov')
```

When `file.mov` is 3MB or less everything works fine and the file is successfully uploaded. However, for larger files I get a timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/src/vimeo/vimeo/uploads.py", line 79, in __call__
    return do_upload()
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/src/vimeo/vimeo/uploads.py", line 70, in do_upload
    self.upload_segment(upload_uri, _range, video_data, filetype or 'mp4')
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/src/vimeo/vimeo/uploads.py", line 135, in upload_segment
    body=data, headers=request_headers)
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 85, in fetch
    self._async_client.fetch, request, **kwargs))
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 389, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 131, in result
    return super(TracebackFuture, self).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/fabio/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 65, in result
    raise self._exception
HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout
```

This is the vimeo library I am using: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py.

And the Tornado library in my virtual environment is updated to the 3.2.1 version.

Any tips for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Tornado source](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/httpclient.html#HTTPRequest), the default request timeout for an `HTTPClient` which `vimeo` is using is 20 seconds. It looks like the [Vimeo library attempts to upload as much of the video as possible](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py/blob/8b5204043af534fcf02088749bd83093f514549f/vimeo/uploads.py#L134), and then queries the server to see how much was successfully uploaded. It is likely that it is taking over 20 seconds to upload your video and as a result timing out. I'm not convinced they handle this properly though, as you get a timeout error from Tornado, but it seems like they want to support the whole file not being uploaded at once.

You could try modifying the `vimeo` library code that I linked above to have a much longer timeout by changing the linked line in your local copy to something like:

```
    r = HTTPClient().fetch(upload_uri, method="PUT",
                           body=data, headers=request_headers, 
                           request_timeout=9999.0)
```

If that doesn't work you could try raising an issue on their `github` issues tracker, and someone who actually works on the project might be able to help you further.

Comment: I had to add the `request_timeout` as an argument for `.fetch()` rather than for `HTTPClient()`. A part from this, it works great. Thanks!